# how to hide ngb-carousel indicators and prev-next control

Tags: angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I can't hide the ngb-carousel indicators and prev-next control trough the css,
targeting the css class wouldn't work.
Is there any option to hide it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to affect the css of the ng-bootstrap components, you have to disable ViewEncapsulation.

Import it from @angular/core:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core'
```

Then disable it for this component in the @Component declaration:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'your-template-name',
  styleUrls: ['your-template-name.component.scss'],
  template: ` 
... `
})
```

Then you can target the Bootstrap classes etc. as you'd expect in your css file.

You want to disable this on a per-component basis, and only when you need to.