# ngb-Carousel hide next and prev indicators conditonally

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I would like to hide next and prev indicators. 
When i reach last slide i would like to hide next indicator
and when i am on first slide would like to hide prev indicator. 
is there a way we can achieve this.

```
    import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbCarouselConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/carousel-basic.html',
  styleUrls:['src/style.css']
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class NgbdCarouselBasic {
  private data = ["Slide 1","Slide 2","Slide 3"]
  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
    config.interval = 10000;
    config.wrap = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
  }
}
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xWlKZjmX1aG5KmeSASqK?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After [disable ViewEncapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788972/how-to-hide-ngb-carousel-indicators-and-prev-next-control) you can put your ng-carousel into a div

```
<div [ngClass]="{'first':myCarousel.activeId=='0','last':myCarousel.activeId==''+data.length-1}">

  <ngb-carousel ....>
    ....
  </ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

Your .css simply

```
.first .carousel-control-prev
{
    display:none;
}
.last .carousel-control-next {
    display: none;
}
```